# Why won't document.querySelectorAll select elements with attributes set via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

If I print my markup like this:

```
<div popup="1">Some Text</div>
```

I can do a `document.querySelectorAll('[popup="1"]')` and retrieve the node list.
I can even check the value of popup once it's returned in JS with `myDiv.popup`.

However, I want to be creating some DOM elements dynamically.

So I want to create a div, set popup, and add it to the DOM via `(...).appendChild(newDiv)`.

However, if I set "popup" to 1 via JS like `newDiv.popup = 1;` then `querySelectorAll` will not return the object.

Can anyone point out what I may be missing? Is there a way to do what I want without having to keep track of all divs I create just to add the popups?

Comment: Are you allowed/able to use jQuery?

Comment: you are not adding an attribute

Comment: @epascarello Sure enough! It's a property not an attribute. That comment led me to element.createAttribute().

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting an attribute. You need to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
var x = document.getElementById("foo");
x.setAttribute("popup","1");

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[popup="1"]');
console.log(elems);
```

```html
<div id="foo">xxxx</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to add attributes:

```
yourElement.setAttribute("attribute", "value");
```

example:

```
newDiv.setAttribute("popup", "1");
```